# Launching Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I've tried launching tensorboard on Windows. I typed into cmd:

```
cd <my_project_path>
```

then:

```
<path_to_tensorboard_in_python_site_packages> --logdir=<path_to_my_model_logs>
```

But it doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you specify the full path like so: `tensorboard --logdir=I:/project_name/logs/hyperparameter_tuning` ?

Comment: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." error again? Does a simple `tensorboard --help` work?

Comment: It's weird, but it doesn't - nothing happens

Comment: How have you installed tensorflow? From your path I deduce you want to use [Carla](https://github.com/s-nandi/carla-car-detection)? They recommend an installation via pip. I prefer the usage of [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that It was adviced to get tensorboard from site-packages folder. But it doesn't work. The solution is to get tensorboard from Scripts file, e.g. for me it was:

> C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\tensorboard

So at first point to the project directory, e.g. for me:

> cd C:\Users\martin\Desktop\CARLA\WindowsNoEditor_0.9.9.4\PythonAPI\examples

Then:

> C:\Users\martin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\tensorboard --logdir=logs

Then just go to the localhost the cmd advise you to go :)